# How to define an appropriate upper bound integral function

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

Recently, I am doing a course project, and the professor forces us to use Mathematica; however, I am new to Mathematica, and here are my problems.

***Setup***

I am required to, eventually, numerically solve a group of differential equations which look like the form:
$$\frac{dX(t)}{dt}=P(X(t))+F(t)
$$
Here, $X(t)$ is the coloumn vector $(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))^T$, $P(X(t))$ is a polynomial of $X(t)$ which contains terms like $x_i(t)x_j(t)$.

$F(t)$ is the key term for this project. $F(t)$ is a column vector takes form $(F_1[x_1(t)]\cdot x_1^2(t),\,F_2[x_2(t)]\cdot x_2^2(t),\,F_3[x_3(t)]\cdot x_3^2(t))$, where $F_i[x_i(t)]$ is a upper bound function of a complicated function.

Here, I will just present $F_1[x_1(t)]$, since $F_2$ and $F_3$ are similar to $F_1$. I think I can deal with $F_2$ and $F_3$ once I know the way to deal with $F_1$.

$$F_1[x_1(t)]:=\int_0^{\frac{x_1(t)}{3}}\frac{(1+y)(2y-1)^2(2y-3)^2\sin^3(\pi y)[\Gamma(y-1)]^2\Gamma(-2y)}{(y-2)\pi^3}dy
$$
Here $\Gamma$ is the usual gamma function. So far, we are given that $F_1(x)$ has poles at $x=\frac{15}{2}+3n$. Similarly to $F_2$ and $F_3$. Here, we only care about the value before the first pole.

***Main Problem***

Now, here is my question. In order to plug $F_1[x_1(t)]$ in to the differential equation, I tried to numerically compute $F_1(x)$ and define $F_1(x)$ as the following code:

```
I1[x_] := (1 + x)*(2*x - 1)^2*(2*x - 3)^2*Sin[(\[Pi]*x)]^3*
   Gamma[(x - 1)]^2 Gamma[(-2)*x]/((x - 2)*\[Pi]^3)

F1[x_] := NIntegrate[I1[t]*Boole[t < 2.5 - Exp[-NF2]], {t, 0, x/3}]
```

Since we only care $0$ to $15/2$, I set a Boole Function take the value from $0$ to $2.5-\text{Exp(-NF2)}$ $[\text{Note: }15/2\div 3]$, where NF2 is some large number which is given by professor.

After I define the $F_1(x)$, I plug the whole $F_1[x_1(t)]$ into the differential equation, then I get a lot of warning. Can someone help me to fix the issue? Thanks.

Attached is the graph of $F_1(x)$ and the error for directly plug-in procedure. $\alpha(t)$ is $x(t)$ here.[image: Graph of F1][image: Error1][image: Error2][image: Error3]

***Code***

Here is the code I am working on.

```
NF3 = 40; NF2 = 24; Y2 = 
 1/2; Y3 = 0; DR22 = 2; DR32 = 1; DR23 = 1; DR33 = 3; \[Alpha]y = 0;
b1 = 41/3 + 8/3*Y2^2*NF2*DR22*DR32;
b2 = 19/3 - 4*NF2*DR32/3;
b3 = 14 - 4*NF3*DR23/3;
c1 = 199/9 + 8/3*Y2^4*NF2*DR22*DR32;
c2 = 35/3 + 49*NF2*DR32/3;
c3 = -52 + 76*NF3*DR23/3;
d1 = 88/3 + 32/3*Y2^2*NF2*DR22*DR32;
d2 = 24 + 16/3*NF2*DR32;
d3 = 9 + 3*NF3*DR23;
e1 = 9 + 6*Y2^2*NF2*DR22*DR32;
e2 = 3 + 4*Y2^2*NF2*DR32;
e3 = 11/3 + 4*NF3*Y3^2*DR23;

NC2 = 2;
NC3 = 3;
I1[x_] := (1 + x)*(2*x - 1)^2*(2*x - 3)^2*Sin[(\[Pi]*x)]^3*
   Gamma[(x - 1)]^2 Gamma[(-2)*x]/((x - 2)*\[Pi]^3);
F1[x_] := NIntegrate[I1[t]*Boole[t < 2.5 - Exp[-NF2]], {t, 0, x/3}];
I22[x_] := (NC2^2 - 1)/NC2 + (20 - 43 x + 32 x^2 - 14 x^3 + 4 x^4)*
    NC2/(2*(2 x - 1)*(2 x - 3)*(1 - x^2));
I23[x_] := (NC3^2 - 1)/NC3 + (20 - 43 x + 32 x^2 - 14 x^3 + 4 x^4)*
    NC3/(2*(2 x - 1)*(2 x - 3)*(1 - x^2));
H12[x_] := -11/2*NC2 + 
   NIntegrate[I1[t]*I22[t]*Boole[t < 1 - Exp[-NF3]], {t, 0, x/3}];
H13[x_] := -11/2*NC3 + 
   NIntegrate[I1[t]*I22[t]*Boole[t < 1 - Exp[-NF3]], {t, 0, x/3}];
Plot[F1[t], {t, 0, 8}]

A1 = 4*\[Alpha]1[t]*NF2*Y2^2*DR22*DR32;
A2 = 2*\[Alpha]2[t]*NF2*DR32;
A3 = 2*\[Alpha]3[t]*NF3*DR23;

odeg1 = 2*A1*\[Alpha]1[t]*F1[A1]/(3*NF2) + 
    D[\[Alpha]1[t], 
     t] == (b1 + c1*\[Alpha]1[t] + d1*\[Alpha]3[t] + 
      e1*\[Alpha]2[t] - 17*\[Alpha]y/3)*\[Alpha]1[t]^2;
odeg2 = 2*A2*\[Alpha]2[t]*H12[A2]/(3*NF2) + 
    D[\[Alpha]2[t], 
     t] == (-b2 + c2*\[Alpha]2[t] + d2*\[Alpha]3[t] + 
      e2*\[Alpha]1[t] - 3*\[Alpha]y)*\[Alpha]2[t]^2;
odeg3 = 2*A3*\[Alpha]3[t]*H13[A3]/(3*NF3) + 
    D[\[Alpha]3[t], 
     t] == (-b3 + c3*\[Alpha]3[t] + d3*\[Alpha]2[t] + 
      e3*\[Alpha]1[t] - 4*\[Alpha]y)*\[Alpha]3[t]^2;
Ncorrect = 
  NDSolve[{odeg1, odeg2, 
    odeg3, \[Alpha]1[3] == 0.00084, \[Alpha]2[3] == 
     0.00256, \[Alpha]3[3] == 
     0.0061}, {\[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2, \[Alpha]3}, {t, 0, 20}];
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Alpha]1[t], \[Alpha]2[t], \[Alpha]3[t]} /. 
   Ncorrect], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> 1, AxesLabel -> {t, Strength}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Please post a copy-pastable code, not only an image of a code, so that people can play with it on their computers.

Comment: @corey979 The only thing one needs is the code in the main problem. Other codes are irrelevant.

Comment: You seem to not understand how this site work. Please [take the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @corey979 Apparently not. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Can't analyse in detail, but try `F1[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[I1[t]*Boole[t < 25/10 - Exp[-NF2]], {t, 0, x/3}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 20]; `  and `H12[x_?NumericQ] := -11/2*NC2 + 
   NIntegrate[I1[t]*I22[t]*Boole[t < 1 - Exp[-NF3]], {t, 0, x/3}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 20]; `  ,same for H13 and `Ncorrect = 
 NDSolve[Rationalize[{odeg1, odeg2, 
    odeg3, \[Alpha]1[3] == 0.00084, \[Alpha]2[3] == 
     0.00256, \[Alpha]3[3] == 0.0061}, 
   0], {\[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2, \[Alpha]3}, {t, 0, 20}, MaxSteps -> 200,
   WorkingPrecision -> 20] `

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks. I will give a try.

Comment: @Akku14 According to the code you gave to me, it says $t=\alpha 2[t]$ is not a valid limit of integration. Same for $\alpha 3[t]$. However, the issue for $\alpha 1[t]$ seems to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `x_?NumericQ` which means the function evaluates only for numerical values should fix your problem. However, to compute `F1`, instead of computing the (indefinite) numerical integral one can turn it into a first-order DE:

$f(x)=\int_0^x g(t) \, dt \implies f'(x)=g(x)$ with $f(0)=0$

and solve this using `NDSolve` instead, which is *much* faster as it computes the values of `F1` over the entire range in one go. Also, the solution is returned as an `InterpolatingFunction` so the issue that you faced disappears. But, because of the singularities of $g(x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=5/2$, one has to deal with these separately. To do this, perform series expansion about $x=5/2$ and subtract of the resulting pole there, (which leads to a logarithmic singularity).